# How to create a Data base row in Wordpress for uploaded objects to Amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, php, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my Wordpress website Users can upload video files directly to a Amazon S3 bucket (So the files don't go through my webserver.) How i should keep track of the added objects (i.e: where and how i should add a data entry in my Wordpress Database )

Comment: Please provide more information. Are the videos associated with a post, a user, or other? Where do you have access to the details of the upload: javascript or php?

Comment: @Tristan The Videos are associated to a specific user who has uploaded them. and you have access to the details of upload by javascript

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information provided you could post the image data using ajax. The below is simple ajax with placeholder data for the image.

```
var imgData = {author: 'the-author-id', img_url: 'the-url', img_type: 'the-img-type'}

$.ajax({
    data : JSON.stringify(imgData),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST',
    url: 'your-wordpress-post-url',
    success: function () {
        // do something with the success result from backend
    }
});
```

And within WordPress you would use `wp_insert_attachment()`

```
<?php

// Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
$attachment = array(
    'post_author' => $_POST['author'], 
    'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
    'guid' => $_POST['img_url'], 
    'post_mime_type' => $_POST['img_type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $_POST['img_url'] ),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
);

// Insert the attachment.
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment );

// if fail $attach_id is 0
echo json_encode(array('attach_id' => $attach_id));
?>
```